# why the sexp has array in the end

Tags: ruby, parsing

```
RubyParser.new.parse "1+1" 
s(:call, s(:lit, 1), :+, s(:array, s(:lit, 1)))
```

Above code is from [this link](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/12/ruby_ruby_parser)

Why there is array after + in the Sexp. I am just trying to learn ruby parser and the whole AST thing. I have been programming for a while but have no formal education in computer science. So do point to good article which explains AST etc. Please no dragon book. I tried couple of times but couldn't understand much of that book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby (or at least in MRI), all message sends have exactly one argument: an array. If you send a message with no arguments, the array will simply be empty, if you send a message with one argument (as is the case in this example), the array will have one element.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Did this behavior change in ruby 1.9? I will try this in rubinius to see what behavior is shown there.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: the array represents the parameter list. The "+" message is sent to the first "1" with a list of parameters, which has only one item, the second "1".